# ActionCable with SSL not working in production environment

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, unicorn, actioncable

I am using ActionCable in rails 5.2 and deployed the code on AWS with nginx server.
Previously WebSocket was working when I was working on http but when i have implemented SSL, it stopped working. For SSL I have implemented load balancer in AWS. I am using Unicorn as rails application server.

my ActionCable url is:

```
SOCKET_URL: wss://example.com/cable
```

```
Started GET "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 182.74.85.106 at 2019-10-30 14:32:05 +0000
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 182.74.85.106 at 2019-10-30 14:32:05 +0000
```

configuration in my production.rb file is:

```
config.action_cable.url = ENV["SOCKET_URL"]
ActionCable.server.config.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

my nginx conf is:

```
upstream unicorn {
    server unix:/usr/share/nginx/html/demo_app/shared/tmp/unicorn.demo_app.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/demo_app/current/public;

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

        location @unicorn {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://unicorn;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste below lines in your nginx.conf and try.

```
location /cable {  
    proxy_pass http://unicorn/cable;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```